# Avoid dynamic allocation in local scope

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, reference

There is a snippet from my code:

```
const std::pair<Info, const ElementHandler&>& handle () const {
                    FileHandler fileHandler = FileHandler();
                    std::pair<Info, const ElementHandler&> result = std::pair<Info, const FileHandler&> ( info, fileHandler );
                    return result;
                }
```

I have the following compilation error:

```
error: cannot declare field ‘std::pair<Synchronizer::Info, Synchronizer::ElementHandler>::second’ to be of abstract type ‘Synchronizer::ElementHandler’
```

How I can write the code to preserve the idea? Is it possible, or I need use pointers and dynamic allocation?

Comment: Regardless of the compilation errors, you should never return a reference to a locally declared variable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Avoid dynamic allocation in local scope".

If that's the driving need behind your broken code, then I won't follow the trend by telling you how to fix it to do what you don't want ;-).  Instead, you have to consider the implications properly.  You must have some variable with a scope that matches the caller's needs.  Local automatic variables must be ruled out - they are destroyed when the function returns.  So, you could:

- use a function scoped `static` variable, or a global variable, but that will be the same variable each time the function is called and there could be thread-safety issues (your compiler may support some thread-specific keyword, and POSIX has functions to support thread-specific data - but 1-object-per-thread may still be too limiting)
- create some buffer with space for many variables, and take control of their lifetime and reuse in some way that suits the client code (e.g. rotate through an array knowing that the client will release them in the order they're returned and never need more than the array size concurrently)
- let the client code worry about lifetimes (they probably know more than you) and provide a variable you're to load with the result (e.g. `bool load_my_x(X&);`)

  - a problem here is that the caller needs to allocate space for FileHandler and not simply ElementHandler

Answer (score 1):

1. Allocate `fileHandler` with `new`, or possibly as some kind of `shared_ptr`. The current reference to `fileHandler` will be invalid as soon as the function exits.
2. Return `result` by value and not by reference.

Comment: i assume he started down this path since elementhandler is virtual

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic allocation anyway.

Within your function you are creating a local variable 'fileHandler' and you return a reference to it.  As soon as the function returns, 'fileHandler' goes out of scope and is destructed, making the reference invalid.

I think you can nicely solve this problem using smart pointers (unique_ptr, shared_ptr, ...).  Your smart pointer can point to ElementHandler, and if ElementHandler has a virtual destructor, it is correctly destructed if the pair is deleted or goes out of scope.

Comment: prefer unique_ptr to shared_ptr wherever possible, including here.

Comment: @MooingDuck Actually, here is probably a case where `shared_ptr` is preferable.  What he really needs is value semantics, but value semantics doesn't work with polymorphism.  `shared_ptr` has true value semantics.  Although the pointed to object acquires reference semantics, the fact that it is a pointer to const (here) means that the distinction is moot.